# How to detect if between two points there is a black pixel in a binary picture? C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

Some context about the problem: I have a race path in an image of black and white pixels. An I want to put random points in the width and height of the image and only keep with those that aren`t touching any black point.
It looks like this:

[image]

In the picture I only want to keep the 2 yellow point because it hasn't any black point between the red and that point.

My first approach to solve this is to store all the pixels in an array or matrix, filled with 0 for white pixels and 1 for black pixels and find some algorithm to check if it has any 1 between two given positions. It makes me struggling because if the two points have an angle between they, how can I do to find any black pixel.
Also the image is 1800 x 904 size, so I think to store the pixels in a matrix isn`t the best way to represent the picture because it will be doing so many loops.

I want to know if there is a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: What about drawing a black line between your red and yellow point with XOR, and check if one point of your drawed line has a white pixel ? it will be faster than check all the matrix

Comment: "store all the pixels in an array or matrix" you already have this. This is what an image is.

Comment: Presumably, you already know how to draw a line from point RED to point YELLOW.  Do the same thing, but instead of poking the color into the pixel, check the pixel's color.  If the pixel is black, then there is a black pixel along the line, the loop can fast return, and the YELLOW point can be removed from the set.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a Bresenham segment between the endpoints an check presence of a black pixel along it.

If your image is described by curves rather than a bitmap, the solution will be very different but you have to give us more information.